# How many ways to select 5 cards with at least one king.

Tags: permutations, combinations

I am given a deck of $52$ cards in which I have to select $5$ card which has at least one king.
So I selected one king out of $4$ and then remaining from deck as
$$^4C_1. ^{51}C_4$$ which however gives wrong answer but subtracting total combination from combination with no gives right answer
$$^{52}C_5- ^{48}C_5$$ So, why is first approach wrong?

Comment: Go over 1 - "the probability to select no king": 1-48/52*47/51*46/50*45/49*44/49

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are "duplicating combinations", because the same king that you choose out of $4$ kings in one combination, can be chosen out of $51$ cards in another combination.

Instead, calculate the total number of combinations, and then subtract the number of combinations with no kings at all:

$$\binom{52}{5}-\binom{52-4}{5}$$

Answer (score 1):

first expression is wrong answer.

reasoning: in first expression, we are counting some combinations twice. let me explain with an example. one combination is: $\{\spadesuit K, \heartsuit K, \spadesuit 1, \spadesuit 2,\spadesuit3\}$ and another one is: $\{\heartsuit K, \spadesuit K, \spadesuit 1, \spadesuit 2, \spadesuit 3\}$. These two combinations have been counted twice in first expression.